# Can nsupdate.exe on Windows updates BIND on Linux?

Tags: linux, windows, bind

Can nsupdate.exe on Windows (from BIND for Windows) updates a BIND DNS server on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be no problem, all the protocols should be the same in the client if you're taking it from a BIND build for Windows and running against a BIND server.  Test it on a development BIND server before using in production if you're not sure about it.  I'd also recommend making sure you are using the same version on the client as you are on the server.